# Oracle application performance issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have developed a **oracle apex** application using oracle **apex 19.1** version and oracle **11gr2 xe oracle database**, which has performance issue like slow login and slow loading of home page.

while troubleshooting I found that when I deployed a copy of same application with new application ID then the both application working fine and after **some days (2,3)** it become slow again then again I delete duplicate application application and recreate a duplicate application with **new application id** then again it become fast, I could not find the reason behind it, if any one can help me to understand this behavior, I would really appreciate them.

***I must add here that performance improve only when new duplicate application has a new application id, if reusing old application id then no improvement.***

Comment: I agree with Littlefoot, but I'll add that 11G XE is quite old at this point. I recommend upgrading to 18C XE or converting to the Oracle Cloud Free Tier where you get an even larger database (20 G) that you don't even have to maintain (Oracle will do that for you). https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/

Answer (score 1):

Who knows? I don't, but - you might find out.

- run the application (from App. Builder)
- when on home page, enable debug (on the toolbar at the bottom of the page)
- reload
- view debug
- check *events* that take a lot of time to finish - that's where you should start the investigation

  - if it is something obvious, fine - fix it. If not, share that information with us - someone might be able to assist